# Next.js Routing: File Changes Impacting Navigation - How to Manage Routes Effectively

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes, url-routing, next.js13

[image] I want that when i use routing from **allprojects** it should use **[projectid] ** how to do it?
normaly we all know that in next js we do file based routing and in dynamic routing case we make anoter file wrapping with [] and rest of the work next do for use what if we make another file and let it use the same dynammic file while routing

I've tried giving same routing method used in page.js as same i used in allprojects . i can't resolving how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear much about your question but according to my understanding if you want the route like - allprojects/[projectid] then you just need to place **[projectid]** folder inside **allprojects** and inside **[projectid]** you will need layout.jsx and page.jsx. After that you can achieve dynamic route for allprojects.

Let me know if your requirement is something else. I can help you in this case because I am using routing like this in multiple projects.

Comment: surprisingly it worked without any changes needed

Comment: Ohhh that's cool.